# How does statsmodels ARIMA.forecast() work?

Tags: statsmodels, predict, arima, forecast

I simulated an ARMA Process and tried to forecast it with statsmodels.
I plotted the true value and the forecasted values.

I read that out-of-sample forecasts tend to converge to the sample mean for a long forecasting period. Can someone describe how this forecasts are calculated? I read in the documentation that they transform the arma model into a state space model and then forecast the next value via kalman filter, is this correct? Is then the calculated value t+1 used for the next prediction t+2?
However if I created another AR process and shifted it upwards
and mix the two arrays and then again do a forecast.

How does statsmodels ARIMA forecast "learn" the ups and downs of the data?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA


ar = np.array([1, -0.9])
ma = np.array([1])



AR_object = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)



a = AR_object.generate_sample(nsample=200)
b = AR_object.generate_sample(nsample=200)+10

ab = [item for sublist in zip(a, b) for item in sublist]


train = a[:100]
test = a[100:]
train_ab = ab[:100]
test_ab = ab[100:200]

plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)

model = ARIMA(train, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(test))[0]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(test, color= 'green')
plt.plot(forecast, color='red')


plt.figure()
model = ARIMA(train_ab, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
forecast_ab = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(test_ab))[0]

plt.plot(test_ab, color= 'green')
plt.plot(forecast_ab, color='red')
```